# Using painted graphics of other java files

Tags: java, swing, animation, 2d-games

Suppose I have a java file named `BouncingBalls.java` and I have a separate java file called `MyAnimation.java`. MyAnimation only contains the GUI that lets me play BouncingBalls animation when I click it from a `JList`. Note that MyAnimation should NOT close when this happens. Bouncing Balls should simply play on a `JPanel` set up specifically for that, let's call that panel `animationPanel`. This won't be a problem if I only I have 1 animation to choose from but I plan to have about 5. Should I really create a new java file for that or is the paint method overloadable?

Comment: Why not make each of these animations provide it's own component and simply switch that one out? Just let each of your animations implement an appropriate self-defined interface

Comment: ..........................hello?

Comment: @Paul Can you elaborate that a bit?

Comment: @ArcIX to be honest, this question is far too broad be more specific. I.e. switching out JPanels vs simply changing the rendering-routine depends upon the way the animation is implemented. The way the fps is handled determines how to implement the rendering, ... . You'll have to elaborate upon what your code looks like before I can provide any help except some general patterns

Comment: @Paul Ok I see. I'll ask again once I complete the driver. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

> Bouncing Balls should simply play on a JPanel set up specifically for that, let's call that panel animationPanel. This won't be a problem if I only I have 1 animation to choose from but I plan to have about 5. Should I really create a new java file for that or is the paint method overloadable?

Probably you will want a separate JPanel for each, if they are very different from each other. If each is in its own JPanel, it is easy to swap them with a CardLayout. Is it possible to have only one drawing JPanel and instead swap out non-component models that drive the animation? Yes, but that would be trickier to implement, but likely it could be done. If you went this route, you would want to go full Model-View-Controller (MVC) program design where the view, your drawing JPanel would display different animations depending on which model is selected by the user via the JList.

As always, the devil's in the details -- if you need a more detailed answer, you'll want to provide more details and [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.